# BadImageFormatException porting WPF app to .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1

I am currently porting our .Net Framework 4.7.2 WPF app to .Net Core 3.1. So far most of it worked well. Thing is, I need to load assemblies and read some resources (language files) at startup.

Now every time my app tries to read the WPF app assembly, I get an `BadImageFormatException` saying that it is missing an manifest. Usually these are generated by default, but even adding my own does not get it to work.

That's where it happens (first line):

```
var name = AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(path);
if (MasterCore.CoreLibraries.Any(l => l == name)) return null;
assem = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
```

I tried to PEVerify (which obviously does not work as it's a .Net Core app) and looked for .Net Core alternatives but couldn't find any.

Anyone had a similiar issue? I don't get what's the issue here. Just FYI I already ported all .Net Framework references to either Standard or Core.

Comment: You've checked the assembly targets the same framework as that loading it?

Comment: All used assemblies use `netcoreapp3.1` or alternatively `netstandard2.0`. So yes, that shouldn't be the problem. Moreover why would it say that the WPF assembly is missing a manifest? That got nothing to do with referenced assemblies and their target framework(s).

Comment: Eityer it just can't read the assembly at all or the name isn't where it's looking. Maybe the manifest supplies the assembly name in net core. I dunno. It's a long time since i dynamically loaded assemblies. Even then, i think i would have been using mef.

Comment: I found out that the `.exe` is indeed just a wrapper to get things started but not really a valid assembly. So I just ignored that and used the generated `.dll` instead. The exception occurs still but can be suppressed. Edit: At least all popular decompilers had issues with the executable but worked fine on the library.